# ValueError: Cannot assign "'827'": "Course_Content.course_outline_id" must be a "Course_Outline" instance

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

So in my django view i am trying to pass the outline instance but it keeps saying ValueError: Cannot assign "'827'": "Course_Content.course_outline_id" must be a "Course_Outline" instance. I already tried converting it to int. But i dont know what i am doing wrong. I already tried using outline_instance.id so it would be more specific it still does not work.

**views.py**

```
class UpdateCourseOutline(View):
    def post(self, request):
        outline_id = request.POST.get('outline_id', None)
        new_topic = request.POST.get('new_topic', None)
        new_week = request.POST.get('new_week', None)
        new_clo = request.POST.get('new_clo', None)
        new_course_content_data = json.loads(request.POST.get('new-course_content', '[]'))
        deleted_course_content_data = json.loads(request.POST.get('deleted-course_content', '[]'))
        new_added_course_content_data = request.POST.getlist('add-new-course_content[]')
        
        # Update Course_Outline details
        outline = get_object_or_404(Course_Outline, id=outline_id)
        outline.topic = new_topic
        outline.week = new_week
        outline.course_learning_outcomes = new_clo
        outline.save()
        print("outline - type(outline_id):", type(outline_id))

        # Add new Course_Content items
        self.add_course_content(int(outline_id), new_added_course_content_data)

        # Update Course_Content details
        self.update_course_content(outline_id, new_course_content_data)

        # Delete Course_Content items
        self.delete_course_content(deleted_course_content_data)

        # Retrieve the updated outline with course content
        updated_outline = Course_Outline.objects.values('id', 'topic', 'week', 'course_learning_outcomes').get(id=outline_id)
        updated_outline['course_content'] = list(Course_Content.objects.filter(course_outline_id=outline_id).values('id', 'course_content'))

        data = {
            'success': True,
            'message': 'Course outline updated successfully!',
            'outline_id': updated_outline['id'],
            'topic': updated_outline['topic'],
            'week': updated_outline['week'],
            'course_learning_outcomes': updated_outline['course_learning_outcomes'],
            'course_content': updated_outline['course_content'],
            # Add other fields if needed
        }
            
        return JsonResponse(data)

    def add_course_content(self, outline_id, new_values):
        try:
            # Get the Course_Outline instance based on the outline_id
            outline_instance = get_object_or_404(Course_Outline, id=outline_id)

            # Log information for debugging
            print("add_course_content - outline_id:", outline_id)
            print("add_course_content - type(outline_id):", type(outline_id))
            print(outline_instance)
            print(outline_instance.id)
            print(type(outline_instance.id))

            # Iterate over new values and create Course_Content instances
            for entry in new_values:
                # If 'id' is None, it's a new item
                if entry['id'] is None:
                    content_text = entry['content']
                    # Create new entry for added content with the correct Course_Outline instance
                    Course_Content.objects.create(course_outline=outline_instance, course_content=content_text)

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            print(f"Error adding course content: Course_Outline with id {outline_id} does not exist.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error adding course content: {e}")
```

**models.py**

```
class Course_Outline(models.Model):
    syllabus_ai_id = models.ForeignKey(Syllabus_AI, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    week = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    topic = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    course_learning_outcomes = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

class Course_Content(models.Model):
    course_outline_id = models.ForeignKey(Course_Outline, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course_content = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Please look at the code trying to create a Course_Content, "Course_Content.objects.create(course_outline=outline_instance, course_content=content_text)". According to your Course_Content model, It should be course_outline_id=outline_instance, not course_outline=outline_instance

Comment: @Temi i already tried that but the problem is still there. It still says `ValueError: Cannot assign "'827'": "Course_Content.course_outline_id" must be a "Course_Outline" instance.`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
course_outline_id_id = 827
```

as you named your foreign key as `course_outline_id` which shall receive as object, you can set the relationship by pk using `_id` attribute.

Comment: where exactly do I put that?
`Course_Content.objects.create(course_outline=outline_instance, course_content=content_text)`
this part is where im trying to fix. i already tried `course_outline_id_id` to replace `course_outline`.

Comment: What is the value of `outline_instance`?

Comment: The value of the `outline_instance` is the `outline_id` which I am trying to pass there but it does not work apparently. I already converted it into an integer but the error keeps appearing.